# Android Lollipop - Dynamically added view has weird green-blue color overlay

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-view

My MotoX (2013) recently updated to Android 5.1 (it was at 4.4.4 previously).  I am now noticing a weird bug whenever I dynamically add a view in my app.  I have an add component button that will add a view to the screen when a button is pressed.  In Android 4.4.4 it has worked fine.  However when I updated to 5.1, the view I'm adding gets a weird blue-green color over the entire view:

[image]

Then, as I start to change things on the view, part of the blue-green will go away.  For example, changing the rating will make the RatingsBar go back to normal but not the rest of the view:

[image]

Finally, if I start swiping up and down on the screen (this added view is inside a scroll view), the view will go back to normal.

(see comments for the third link. My rep won't allow me to post images or >3 links)

This is what the view is supposed to look like, and what it looks like in other android versions.  I'd also like to point out I haven't noticed this in the TestFairy screencaps I've recorded of my client who does have Android 5.x.

What could this be?  Anything I should test for or any other info you need?
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

So, after a little more testing, I realized all components shared a style that had the background defined as `@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame`.  After taking that out, it fixed my problem.

My new question is....why?

Comment: Here is that third link.  The component normally looks like this, and will eventually go back to this if I adjust the scroll http://i.imgur.com/hXoCwMx.jpg

Comment: Please post some code and layouts

Comment: I figured out that it was my background that was causing the problem.  See update.